# firebase.intializeApp is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, telegram-bot

so im stuck at this error. Im making a telegram bot with the telegram bot api and now im trying to set up a firebae DB to save the score of a group member - so the score is not resetted after restarting the bot. can someone tell me what the problem is? i read a lot of other issues here with similiar problems, but none of these answers fixed my problem.

**bot.js**

```
var TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
var firebase = require('firebase');

var token = 'mytoken';
// Setup polling way
var bot = new TelegramBot(token, {polling: true});

var app = firebase.intializeApp({
  serviceAccount: "C:/Mayer/scorebot/telegramscorebot.json",
  databaseURL: "https://blazing-heat-2008.firebaseio.com/"
});


/* function Person(name, score) {
this.name = name;
this.score = score;
}

var member = new Array();
member[0] = new Person("name1", 0);
member[1] = new Person("name2", 0);
member[2] = new Person("name3", 0);
member[3] = new Person("name4", 0);
member[4] = new Person("name5", 0); */

bot.onText(/\/echo (.+)/, function (msg, match) {
  var fromId = msg.from.id;
  if (match[1] == 'test') {
  var resp = match[1];
  bot.sendMessage(fromId, resp); }
  else {
  bot.sendMessage(fromId, 'error!!');}
});

bot.onText(/\/vote (.+)/, function (msg, match) {
  var fromId = msg.from.id;

for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    if(member[i].name == match[1]){
        member[i].score += 1;
        bot.sendMessage(fromId, member[i].name + ' hat einen Score von ' +         member[i].score);}
}
});
```

**package.json**

```
   {
   "name": "scorebot",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "",
   "main": "bot.js",
   "scripts": {
     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node bot.js"
   },
   "author": "me",
   "license": "ISC",
   "dependencies": {
     "bower": "1.7.9",
    "firebase": "3.0.2"
   }
 }
```

**Error message**

```
 bot.js:8 var app = firebase.intializeApp({
                    ^

  TypeError: firebase.intializeApp is not a function
      at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Mayer\scorebot\bot.js:8:20)
      at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
      at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
      at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
      at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
      at startup (node.js:141:18)
      at node.js:933:3
```

Answer (score 10):

You have a typo in firebase.intializeApp.

It should be initializeApp.

```
var app = firebase.initializeApp({...});
```

Comment: I also did typo like firebase.initialzeApp({...}); And get the same error :( Thank's man

Answer (score 7):

See the docs here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase

You need to require the 'app' when in the browser context like so...

```
const firebase = require('firebase/app');

const app = firebase.initializeApp({ ... });
```

Answer (score 3):

For those reading this later, I'm using ES Modules from Node v14 and solved it with:

```
import firebase from '@firebase/app';
import "@firebase/database";

firebase.default.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
let db = firebase.default.database();
```

☕️

Answer (score 0):

Oops! You misspelled "initialize". But pho3nixf1re said it best.